# Unable to get frame accurate timecode in adobe animate CC

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-cs5, flashdevelop, ng-animate

I am using adobe animate tool to develop a flash player which will allow users to annotate and tag faces of people in a video. So user plays video he pauses it and draws a rectangle around a visible face. 
WHat i need is a frame accurate time code of this frame when user has pause. How can I do that using flash animate CC and action script?

Comment: and I dont want to convert timestamp into timecode. as that will be error prone

Comment: Use `AppendBytes()` method to extract (and count) individual frame bytes and manually feed them to the **NetStream** decoder.

Answer (score 0):

If you're playing the video via the NetStream class, can't you just use the `NetStream.time` property? I think that's accurate to 1ms.

[AS3 NetStream class](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#time)

Comment: `NetStream.time` is only per second (not in milliseconds). Asker's only hope is to use `AppendBytes` (if video file has supported a/v codecs) and manually feed each frame to the decoder. This way they'll know what frame number they are seeing at present moment. For this they'll need a good understand bytes structure of their file format.

Comment: It's measured in seconds, yes, but it's a Number. Just checking with playback of a local flv via NetStream and I'm getting the 'time' value showing 0.048, 0.092, 0.106 etc on subsequent frames.